# TypeError: takes no arguments (2 given) when using WSGI in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I am using mod-wsgi with Apache 2.2

I have the following in WSGI script

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '<path to my app>')

from optimization_app import optimizeInstances as application
```

and `optimization_app.py` as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.Optimization import OptimizationAlgo

def optimizeInstances():
    optimization_app = Flask(__name__)
    api = Api(optimization_app)
    api.add_resource(OptimizationAlgo, '/instances')
```

When I try to access the app url, I get the following in my apache error_log

```
TypeError: optimizeInstances() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because you used it as the WSGI `application` object.

```
from optimization_app import optimizeInstances as application
```

A WSGI application is required to accept two parameters `environ` and `start_response`. So when the WSGI server is calling that function to have your application handle a request it is failing with that error.

The way you are using that function is simply wrong. Your actual WSGI application is being created inside of that function in local scope, so how would it be accessed anyway.

Would suggest you check back and look at the Flask getting started documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to use WSGI for the first time. I added more details in another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764390/using-python-flask-restful-with-mod-wsgi). Could you take a look?

Comment: This will working when using `Flask`, but with `Tornado` it will need some changes in the application new instance.

Comment: If you are talking native Tornado application, which is async, then is entirely different. If you were talking about Tornado WSGI handler, then there may be some relevance. Sounds like you are comparing something totally different.

Answer (score -1):

As I see u defined optimizeInstances() with No arguments. You might be calling optimizeInstances() function by passing 2 arguments to it.

Comment: I changed the name and made sure these are the only 2 places I use it in.

Comment: How you are calling that funtion. it should be just like: optimizeInstances()

Comment: cannot have anything braces () ,because you defined it without input arguments

Comment: The WSGI script alone is importing the function. Defining it without '()' gives an error.

Comment: sorry typing mistake. I mean while calling that optimizeInstances() it cannot have anything inside braces ()